# Proper place to setup React Router history listener

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, browser-history

I'm trying to set up a history listener at the topmost level so that every time the location changes, some code is executed (Google Analytics tracking in my case).

Currently, my App.js looks like this:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```

As I understand, I can only use `history` inside `BrowserRouter`, but it can only have one child, so I can only put it inside `Switch`, but then I'll have to put it inside every component under Switch, which I can't do since I want it to run only once. If I just add a custom component under `Switch` without wrapping it into a `Router`, there's no history.

What should I change to make it work? Is it possible to get an instance of `history` in the `App.js` code? Is it possible to achieve using a custom component or a HOC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the easiest option is the Update component -- https://github.com/pshrmn/rrc/blob/master/docs/OnUpdate.md

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Route` which will get rendered unconditionally.
Try something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <React.Fragment>
                <Route component={HistoryListenerComponent}/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
                    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}/>
                </Switch>
            </React.Fragment>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

So `HistoryListenerComponent` is always rendered and you can `listen` from its `componentDidMount`.

Comment: This is not a good recommendation. There is `history` designed for that, and router component for every use case.

Comment: `HistoryListenerComponent` gets a `history` object provided by React Router through `props.history`. And this object should be used for listening.

Comment: `HistoryListenerComponent` gets a `history` object that is true. But you forgot that this is necessary only for within react-router application, while google analytics does not need to use react-router, `history` is enough and it is also why you can provide it through `props`.

Answer (score 1):

Heres what worked for me:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Now just wrap the component where you are using React-ga with withRouter like this:

```
    componentDidMount=()=>{
         ReactGa.initialize('00000'); //enter id
        ReactGa.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
        
        this.props.history.listen(location => {
            ReactGa.set({ page: location.pathname }); // Update the user's current page
            ReactGa.pageview(location.pathname); // Record a pageview for the given page
        });
    }
    render (){
       return (
         <Switch>
<Route ....>
.....
<Switch>
     );
     }
export default withRouter(ComponentName)
```

**Remember without wrapping withRouter , you cant use this.props.history property.
You cant use custom history listener to BrowserRouter component. It has an inbuilt history prop (i.e this.props.history).**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using [`history`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package, instead of relying on the default one created by react router.

For instance, using `history.listen`:

```
  history.listen((location) => {
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + window.location.search);
  });
```

In my exemple, I use [`react-ga`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ga), as a way to standardize our GA Instrumentation across projects.

Comment: That's the main problem -- where do I get `history` from outside the `Router` component?

Comment: If you're setting Router at the top level then what's outside of that?

Comment: @ulu, you can create it using [`history`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package, instead of relying of the default one created by react router.

Comment: I tried this package. I don't remember what was the exact problem, but I think it the `listen` handler won't fire, because the router created its own `history`

Comment: @ulu you can pass history to use a non default one. It's in the doc